# Google Admin API - Enable chats in IMAP setting

Tags: imap, google-admin-sdk, google-hangouts, google-admin-settings-api

I'm writing some code which will connect to a user's Google apps email account via IMAP and make a complete archive of everything. In this process, I would like to back up the google chat history that is located in the "Chats" label. To do this however, I need to tick the "Show in IMAP" checkbox in the labels window. Is there a way to set this automatically via the Google admin api? I know I have access to read the user's labels and create my own, but I didn't see any reference to modifying existing labels or setting this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to programatically set Chats to show in IMAP. Your app should attempt to access the folder and if it's not visible via IMAP, prompt the user with instructions for manually setting the Chats label to visible via IMAP.

Comment: Hmmm... I was afraid someone would say that. Is there anyway to backup Google chat history without the user's interaction? The reason I ask, is because I want to be able to run this program against a large group of users in our domain and user interaction will probably not be a viable solution; especially if the user no longer works with the company.

Comment: unfortunately, there's no programmatic solution to the problem.

Comment: Oh well, worth a shot. Thanks for your assistance.